# Alternative of "extractall()" of tarfile module in python version 2.4

Tags: python, compatibility, tarfile

`extractall()` from the tarfile module in not present in Python v2.4 
Can you suggest any alternate approach to extract a tarfile in Python v2.4?

Answer (score 2):

The `tarfile` module **is** present in Python 2.4:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/module-tarfile.html

Quoting from the module documentation:

> New in version 2.3.

It is a pure-python module, so it has no C library dependencies that might prevent it from being installed.

The `TarFile.extractall()` function is easily backported:

```
import copy
import operator
import os.path
from tarfile import ExtractError

def extractall(tfile, path=".", members=None):
    directories = []

    if members is None:
        members = tfile

    for tarinfo in members:
        if tarinfo.isdir():
            # Extract directories with a safe mode.
            directories.append(tarinfo)
            tarinfo = copy.copy(tarinfo)
            tarinfo.mode = 0700
        tfile.extract(tarinfo, path)

    # Reverse sort directories.
    directories.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('name'))
    directories.reverse()

    # Set correct owner, mtime and filemode on directories.
    for tarinfo in directories:
        dirpath = os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name)
        try:
            tfile.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)
            tfile.utime(tarinfo, dirpath)
            tfile.chmod(tarinfo, dirpath)
        except ExtractError, e:
            if tfile.errorlevel > 1:
                raise
            else:
                tfile._dbg(1, "tarfile: %s" % e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - a quick check reveals New in *version 2.5.* against extractall.

You will have to:

```
import tarfile

tf = tarfile.TarFile("YourTarFile.tar")
members = tf.getmembers()
for member in members:
    where_to_put_it = "*somthing based on the member path probably!*"
    print 'Extracting', member
    tf.extract(member, where_to_put_it)
```